# particle system: why the hair is not getting the thickness?

Tags: particles

I want to make a fluffy carpet with long and cute fur like those selling in nordstrom...
Here are my settings..
It's not getting any kind of thickness not matter what number I type in under the hair shape section.
And I wonder what other values should I change to get this style I want.
Thanks!!
[image]
[image]
[image]

Comment: I think it's only appear on the cycles render image.

Comment: i'm using cycles

Comment: Are you sure this is the *Rendered* view (key Z) and not the *Material Preview* view? The *Material Preview* mode uses Eevee's settings. By default Eevee only displays a very thin strand. Go to the Eevee render settings, and switch *Hair > Hair Strand Type* from *Strand* to *Strip*. Then you will see the same hair size in *Material Preview* that Cycles will render. Don't forget to switch back to Cycles. Also, make sure you have applied the scale to the carpet (Clrl+A in Object mode) and that it's not oversized but real-world size (Your stands are 1.4 meters long!)